PHP call object difference beetwen ?? vs ?->

What is the difference these operations

$object->items->menu[0]->id ?? null;
$object?->items?->menu[0]?->id ?: null;

Can you explain why and when need to use '?->' operator

Tries

$object->items->menu[0]->id ?? null;
got null as expected
$object?->items?->menu[0]?->id ?: null;


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)


What exact error did you get? And what version of PHP are you running? The second statement seems to work in all currently supported PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/XSogJ

You need to run at least PHP 8.0 before the second statement will work without causing a syntax error. But you should always try to run on a supported version anyway - see PHP Supported Versions for details

If $object is false then. for case error works with warnings in second sample.
I am interested about the second sample why and how it works like this;
For example double question mark check statement isset() so I can add this for nested objects or arrays like example above. But how about ?-> statement?

In the first option, the code will return null if the entire chain before ?? is null.
The second option will the id if the entire chain is valid and not null. If any part of the chain is null it will return null without any errors.
You can get the id of the object using one of these 2 options:
$id = $object->items->menu[0]->id ?? null;
$id = $object?->items?->menu[0]?->id


Thank you for response.
For case success both of the cases returns id.
For case error: first case returns null and second case returns null with (php warning) message.
Questions are: 1)what is the difference; 2)when and why need to use ?-> this operator.

@MirtolipSaitov The difference between the two operators is that the null-safe operator (?->) prevents errors if any part of the access chain is null. The null coalescing operator does not prevent errors from intermediate null values in the chain, it only provides a fallback for the final result.
The null safe operator (?->) is useful for navigating through nested object structures where any part of the chain might be null, as it eliminates the need for explicit null checks at each step.
